# Ekedahl sieve for composite moduli

Tags: nt.number-theory

The following version of a theorem of Ekedahl, known as the Ekedahl sieve, can be found in [this paper](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2015/181-1/p03) by Bhargava and Shankar for example, is stated as follows: let $B$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ having finite measure, and let $Y$ be any closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^n(\mathbb{Z})$ having co-dimension $k \geq 1$. Let $r, M$ be positive real numbers. Then

$$\displaystyle \# \{\mathbf{a} \in rB \cap \mathbb{Z}^n : \mathbf{a} \pmod{p} \in Y(\mathbb{F}_p) \text{ for some prime } p > M \} $$

$$ = O \left(
\frac{r^n}{M^{k-1} \log M} + r^{n-k+1} \right)$$

with the implied constant depending only on $Y$ and $M$.

If we replace the set on the left hand side with the set

$$\displaystyle S_M(r) = \{\mathbf{a} \in rB \cap \mathbb{Z}^n : \mathbf{a} \pmod{p} \in Y(\mathbb{F}_p) \text{ for all } p | q \text{ for some square-free } q > M \}$$

can we obtain an upper bound of comparable strength to the original theorem?

Comment: Minor correction: In the linked paper by Bhargava and Shankar, the implied constant should depend only on $Y$ and $B$.